# checked all/ unchecked all but limit row for check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Num</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>date</th>
            <th><input type="checkbox"  name="m_check" id="m_check" /></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- i have loop for get data -->
        <tr>
            <td>$Num</td>
            <td>$name</td>
            <td>$date</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="e_check[]" value="<?php echo $companys->data[$i]['com_id'] ?>" class ="e_check" id="e_check_<?php echo $companys->data[$i]['com_id'] ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- end loop for get data -->
    </tbody>
```

this is my script

```
$('#m_check').change('change',function() {

       if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('input[name="e_check[]"]:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
            $('#ib_email').removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $('input[name="e_check[]"]:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
            $('#ib_email').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
});
```

my problem is i need when user checked on `m_check` it's check element of `e_check` but check only 10, if my `e_check` more than 10 also.

please help me to correct my `js`

I also see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tm6SH/8/) but i still can not custom my code :(

**Confirm my code is not wrong for user checked all, it's checked element row all, unchecked and it's unchecked all element row but i need when user checked all button it's checked element row limit 10 row top and other is still not check

Comment: replace `$('#m_check').change('change',function() {` with `$('#m_check').on('change','#m_check',function() {`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tm6SH/56/

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like

```
$(document).on('change', '#m_check', function() {

 $('#m_check').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('input[type=checkbox].e_check').map(function (_, el) {
                    $(el).prop('checked', true);
                });
            } else {
                $('input[type=checkbox].e_check').map(function (_, el) {
                    $(el).prop('checked', false);
                });
            }


        });
});
```

or

```
$('#m_check').change(function() {


});
```

**Edited:**

Now when you will click on `<input type="checkbox"  name="m_check" id="m_check" />` All of your records will be checked.

Comment: It's not wrong it for my code but my code is when user checked all, its checked all element row but I want check limit row

Comment: @Songs please see it again now ... I have updated again .. when you will click on check all... all your records will be checked... and when you will un-check the check all ... all your records will be unchecked

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in the jQuery. Prop should be used instead of attributes for the checked prop. Also ':checkbox' is not necessary when name="e_check[]" is already a unique identifier. Lastly, checkout the snippet at the bottom to grab the number. With it, you can set the checking behavior to reflect the number grabbed.

```
$('#m_check').change('change', function () {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('[name="e_check[]"]').prop('checked', true);
        $('#ib_email').removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $('[name="e_check[]"]').prop('checked', false);
        $('#ib_email').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }

    var $num = $(this).closest('table').find('td:first');
    $num = parseInt($num);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do in this way.

I am assuming there is class **tablecheckbox** attachewd to **tbody** to
uniquely identify the checkbox.

```
$('#m_check').on('change',function() {  
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        if( $(".tablecheckbox tr input[type='checkbox']").length > 10){
            $(".tablecheckbox tr input[type='checkbox']").slice(0,10).prop('checked',true)
        }else{
            $(".tablecheckbox tr input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked',true)
        }

        $('#ib_email').removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $(".tablecheckbox tr input[type='checkbox']").slice(0,10).prop('checked',false)
        $('#ib_email').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    });
```